# .htaccess redirect (rewrite) not redirecting with real files paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need all the urls to redirect to index.php where I have a router that handles the url pages, so if someone enters a path (even a real path) it redirects to the index.php:

```
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inmomarco.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.inmomarco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's not working with real paths, if I have a file in /pages/file.php and I try to navigate to it it won't work the above rules, why?

In index.php I get the uri and escape it:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
// some security checks
// an array with the uri as keys and page names as values
```

And in main.php I include the page

```
$include = '/404';

if (array_key_exists($url, $includes)) {
    $include = $url;
}

include($includes[$include]);
```

This is working ok, the problem is the real file paths (in the url bar) that are not parsed by the index.php. Is this supposed to happen? or is there something I can do?

Also if I try to navigate to /index.php it'll display my 404 page, but if I go to another file it'll will display it and the index.php won't do his job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inmomarco.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.inmomarco.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ /index.php [L]
```

Because `-f` and `-d` test for existing file or directory